# does elevated trust in silverlight4 also gives elevation in MAC OS

Tags: silverlight-4.0, partial-trust

Silverlight4 provides an option to run at elevated trust
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-elevated-permissions.aspx

Does anyone know if it also provides certain degree of elevation on MAC OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does provide a degree of elevation.  For instance, you should be able to access the user's files without using the OpenFileDialog.  You will only be allowed to access the current user's documents though; you won't have full access to the hard drive (this is the same on Windows).

Obviously COM is a Windows-only feature.  Hopefully a future version of Silverlight will provide a similar construct on the MAC.

Here's a list of known differences of Silverlight on the MAC.

http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=SilverlightIsnTFullyCrossPlatform